# Android: WiFi-Direct communication when screen is off

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I'm experimenting with P2P communication on Android using WiFi-Direct. I've got a service that searchs for other phones and automatically connects to them if they've been paired before. I like to have this working regardless of whether the screen is on or off.

Android offers an option to keep WiFi alive when the device screen is off. But it looks like it doesn't affect WiFi-Direct. After turning the device's screen off and waiting a minute the `WifiP2pManager` seems to stop discovering new peers.

Has anyone an idea how to fix this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

So what is happening here is that you are calling `startDiscoveryProcess()` 50 seconds after screen is turned off and `startDiscoveryProcess()` is calling itself every 50 seconds. How to stop that process?  You listen for `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON` and if screen is on, we don't send the broadcast to start discovery again.

```
boolean screenOn = true;

BroadcastReceiver screenReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) || intent.getAction().equals("MY_ACTION_WHEN_SCREEN_IS_OFF")) {
            screenOn = false;
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // start discovery process again
                    startDiscoveryProcess();
                }
            }, 50000);
        }  else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            screenOn = true;
        }
    }
};
```

In `onCreate()` of your service, register the receiver:

```
IntentFilter filters = new IntentFilter();
filters.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
filters.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
filters.addAction("MY_ACTION_WHEN_SCREEN_IS_OFF");
registerReceiver(screenReceiver, filters);
```

Then just make sure to have the method we called above:

```
void startDiscoveryProcess() {
    //start discovery process
    // do something...

    // then send the broadcast yourself to do this every 50 seconds because discovery stops at 60 seconds
    if(!screenOn) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("MY_ACTION_WHEN_SCREEN_IS_OFF");
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```